# Add Button On List Item in sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I wanted to add button on my list Item.
List item contains same data from store. 
I want to add submit button on each list item. 
I have tried with Html button but if I click on button then list tap event and button tab events are called.
Is there any way solution for this in sencha.
Thanks

Comment: Could you post your code sample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a class to extend `Ext.dataview.component.DataItem`, and use that in conjunction with `useComponents: true` on your list.  With that class, you can add a button that has a tap event.

Check out this post that gives full instructions on how to do this: http://www.sencha.com/blog/dive-into-dataview-with-sencha-touch-2-beta-2

Answer (score 0):

To add button on list Item I have use following code :

```
<div class="x-button x-button-action button-cls1" <span class="x-button-label" id="accept">Accept</span></div>
```

Using Id of the button we can handle functionality for that button.

This button can be added by using HTML tag also.
Its work foe me.

Thanks...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How the functionality can be handled here ? I am trying to use the code and trying to get the button but it is coming as undefined.